# Use of “I'd go + verb”

Tags: grammar, verbs

I was wondering the validity of the following sentence: “back in the days, **I’d go visit** my grandmother and […]”

A few questions:

- Is the proposition “I’d go visit” correct here? If not, what would you suggest otherwise?
- If I were to extend the sentence, say, to make an enumeration, would infinitives be appropriate? Something along those lines: “**I’d go visit** my grandmother and **make** her soup; **take** her out for a walk and **bring** her safely back home afterwards […]”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “I’d go visit my grandmother and make her soup; take her out for a
> walk and bring her safely back home afterwards […]”

Yes, that is correct. You're using American English, which is fine. In British English, we might say:

“I’d visit my grandmother, make her soup, take her out for a walk, and bring her safely back home afterwards […]”

---

**Note**

You need to know the difference between "back in the **days**" and  "back in the **day**"

The singular is used when the phrase is used alone to indicate an unspecified period, e.g.

"Back in the day, I used to …"

versus

"Back in the days of Kings and Queens, life was much more …"

"Back in the days before the internet, life was much more …"